# Set an array of IBObjects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a xib file that has 10 `UIButton`s in it.

I need to change the color of a random button every second.

Is the only way is to create an individual IBOutlet to every button and then create an array in `ViewDidLoad` with these button or is there any way I can create an array of all the buttons straight from `Interface Builder`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can create an `IBOutletCollection` instead of IBOutlets :

[image: IBOutletCollection]

Then you can add buttons to this collection by drawing the + symbol to each button :

[image: Plus button]

Have fun!